# Comparing all rows of a table Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a DataTable ($dt = New-Object system.Data.datatable) which contains entries as below:

[image]

My objective is :

1. Find servers which same names ,ie , from ServerID column trim the part after underscore (_) (which I achieved via Split()) and then compare with rest of the rows.
2. If the Server Name is same, check the value of all respective "Status" column
3. If none of the columns have "IN PROCESS" in them for the respective server, then print the ServerID.

This is what I came up with but got stuck since values are not returned correctly:

```
foreach($backupid in ($dt.'ServerID' | %{foreach ($y in $_){$y.Split('_')[0]}} | sort -Unique)){
    foreach ($row in $dt){
        if ($row.'ServerID ' -match "^$backupid" -and $row.Status -ne "IN PROCESS" ){
            $row.'ServerID '
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the screenshot the first column header is `Server`, but in your code you use `ServerID` - which one is it?

Comment: My bad @MathiasR.Jessen, it is ServerID. I have corrected the column name, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a hash table to check whether a server id is (not) **IN PROCESS**, like:

```
$dt = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Server,Status
abc_123,"IN PROCESS"
abc_345,"INACTIVE"
abc_546,"INACTIVE"
xyz_123,"INACTIVE"
xyz_457,"INACTIVE"
xyz_230,"INACTIVE"
'@

$InProcess = @{}
$dt | Foreach-Object {
    $Id = $_.Server.Split('_')[0]
    if (!$InProcess.Contains($Id)) { $InProcess[$Id] = $False }
    if ($_.Status -eq 'IN PROCESS') { $InProcess[$Id] = $True }
}

$dt | Foreach-Object {
    $Id = $_.Server.Split('_')[0]
    if ($InProcess[$Id] -eq $False) { $_ }
}

Server  Status
------  ------
xyz_123 INACTIVE
xyz_457 INACTIVE
xyz_230 INACTIVE
```

Comment: Thanks @iRon, this is partially helpful. It is returning the trimmed part of the string ($Id), while my intention is to return the entire cell value for column ServerID

Comment: Thank you ! I see the output now and can make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nested loops, try `Group-Object`!

```
# Group objects by the first part of the Server ID
$dt |Group { $_.ServerID.Split('_')[0] } |Where-Object { 
  # Then find only the groups with no objects where Status is IN_PROGRESS
  $_.Group.Status -notcontains 'IN_PROGRESS'
} |ForEach-Oject -MemberName ServerID     # Output just the Server value
```

Comment: Hi, it does not seems to be returning any value. I think it is taking into consideration all cell values from ServerID irrespective of the status.